# How does bash actually change stdin/stdout/stderr when using redirection/piping

Tags: bash, fork

Unfortunately I've had no luck figuring this out, as everything I find is just on the syntax of redirection, or shallow information about how redirection works.

What I want to know is how bash actually changes `stdin`/`stdout`/`stderr` when you use pipes or redirection. If for example, you execute:

```
ls -la > diroutput.log
```

How does it change `stdout` of `ls` to `diroutput.log`?

I assume it works like this:

- Bash runs `fork(2)` to create a copy of itself
- Forked bash process sets it's `stdout` to `diroutput.log` using something like `freopen(3)`
- Forked bash process runs `execve(2)` or a similar exec function to replace itself with `ls` which now uses the `stdout` setup by bash

But that's just my educated guess.

Comment: No. It's all just file descriptors under the hood.

Comment: I just answered this question over at your other question [How pipes work in Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148401/how-pipes-work-in-linux).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to figure it out using `strace -f` and writing a small proof of concept in C.

It appears that bash just manipulates file descriptors in the child process before calling `execve` as I thought.

Here's how `ls -la > diroutput.log` works (roughly):

- bash calls `fork(2)`
- forked bash process sees the output redirection and opens the file `diroutput.log` using `open(2)`.
- forked bash process replaces the `stdout` file descriptor using the `dup2(2)` syscall
- bash calls `execve(2)` to replace it's executable image with `ls` which then inherits the already setup `stdout`

The relevant syscalls look like this (`strace` output):

```
6924  open("diroutput.log", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3 
6924  dup2(3, 1)                        = 1 
6924  close(3)                          = 0 
6924  execve("/bin/ls", ["ls", "-la"], [/* 77 vars */]) = 0
```